# Calculating the dimensions of constants of a displacement function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

I'm struggling with the following problem, help would be much appreciated!

The displacement of a moving particle over the x-axis can be described by the following function:

$$x(t) = Ae^{-bt} \sin(ct+d)$$

We are using seconds to measure time and meters to measure the displacement.

The constants are:

$$A = 5[?], b = 2[?], c = 4[?], d = 3[?]$$

How can I calculate the dimensions of $A,b,c,d$ and what are the MKS units of $A,b,c,d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the equation needs to be dimensionally consistent (meaning that both sides of the equation have the same units) and that functions that aren't just a variable to some power (e.g. sine, cosine, exponential, etc.) have to have a dimensionless argument.

Dimensional consistency says that $A$ must have the same units as $x$, because the sine and exponential won't carry dimensions. So $A$ has units of meters. Dimensional consistency also says that for quantities to add or subtract, they must have the same units. So $ct$ and $d$ must have the same units.

In order to make the argument of the exponential unitless (if it weren't we could end up with a unit like an exponential meter $e^{meter}$), the units of $b$ and $t$ must cancel. So $b$ has units $1/[t]$=1/s=Hz.

Similarly, the argument of sine should be unitless. However, for trig functions we do keep track of a "unit", namely degrees or radians. The units of the argument of a trig function are naturally radians, so that means $d$ and $ct$ have units of radians. We know the units of $t$ are seconds, so this means $c$ has units rad/s.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A $\sin$ function always returns a dimensionless number.

By consequence $A$ must be expressed in  $\mathrm{m}$, because $x(t)$ is.

The *argument* of a $\sin$ function is also dimensionless (some say $\mathrm{radians}$ but that is dimensionless). So:

$$ct+d$$
is dimensionless, which means that $d$ is dimensionless and:

$$ct$$

is dimensionless too. With $t$ in $\mathrm{s}$, then $c$ must be in $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$.

The exponent of an exponential function (like $e^{-bt}$) is dimensionless, so $b$ must have dimensions $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$.